# Disable Android beam for certain fragments

Tags: android, nfc, ndef, nfc-p2p, android-beam

I need to disable beam and enable on certain fragments.  So I have base fragment, vendor fragment and product fragment.  In base fragment onResume I call:

```
NfcAdapter adapter = NfcAdapter.getDecaultAdapter(getActivity());
adapter.setNdefPushMessage(null, getActivity());
```

So at this point when I put the two NFC devices together, it plays the sound but there is no UI involved. This is what I want.

Then the user goes to products, orders the products and review sthem on the ordersummary fragment.  In this I create my NDEF message and pass it into my NDEF push message callback:

```
mNfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessageCallback(new NfcAdapter.CreateNdefMessageCallback() {
        @Override
        public NdefMessage createNdefMessage(NfcEvent event) {
            NdefMessage message = new NdefMessage((new NdefRecord[]{createMime("application/com.me.myactivity.fragments", mToBeam.getBytes()) }));

            return message;
        }
    }, mActivity);

mNfcAdapter.setOnNdefPushCompleteCallback(new NfcAdapter.OnNdefPushCompleteCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onNdefPushComplete(NfcEvent event) {

        }
    }, mActivity);
```

However on successful transmission I then bring the user back to the product page where in the `onResume()` I call:

```
mNfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessage(null, getActivity());
```

This is called however, now when I bring the two devices together I do get the UI even though the message is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing two different approaches: static and callback based. In order to disable the callback-based approach, you have to call `setNdefPushMessageCallback` passing `null` as the callback:

```
adapter.setNdefPushMessage(null, getActivity());
adapter.setNdefPushMessageCallback(null, getActivity());
adapter.setOnNdefPushCompleteCallback(null, getActivity());
```

Comment: thank you for your solution.  After posting I tried adding the callbacks set to null and it was working well.  I just hadn't an opportunity to update here.